# How to get results from php to html <select> option?

Tags: php, html

i have a select option in index.html , i want to get result from mySQL via php,
but how to get the result from php ,and add results to html  automatically

index.html:

```
<form action="get.php" method="post" >
    <select>
    <option  class="rm" value="trap"><get results from php></option>
.............
    </select>
 </form>
```

If you could show me a working example which does that, or may be any similar idea, it would be good.

Comment: Rename it to index.php and then add your PHP directly on the page.

Comment: but rename to index.php , my site layout  will be change

Comment: no it won't change your layout. The extension lets the file know to also read php or else it won't know its php language, the extension however already validates html/css and with .php also php(and javascript)

Comment: I didnt understand your question.You want to fetch the data from the table in db and want to display in the dropdown select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean. But did you mean something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<select>
<?php
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include "$root/config.php";

$something1 = "something1";
$something2 = "something2";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT from_mysql FROM customers WHERE something1 = :something1 AND from_mysql != :something2 ORDER BY from_mysql');
$stmt->execute(array(':something1' => $something1, ':something2' => $something2));

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

if (empty($results)) { 
    echo 'Error: Please contact technical support!'; 
} else {
foreach( $results as $row ) {
    echo "<option>".$row['from_mysql']."</option>";
}
}
?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. You'll have to use index.**php**

Comment: `error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);` Just no! Don't ever do this, especially on a development website!